# Dynamics CRM 2016.Web API Auth. I have token, now what?

Tags: java, authentication, dynamics-crm, adal, dynamics-crm-2016

Using ADAL libs for java I managed to get Access,Refresh and ID Tokens using my office365 credentials.

Now my intention is using REST Web APIs, my intention is to create an entity, as a proof of concept. Based on my experience with other venders and REST APIs, once you have a valid token, you just add it as a Authorization header like:

```
Authorization=Bearer 709709JHKLJHKJLhHKHKJHKH...etc
```

Is something similar to this in Dynamic CRM 2016?

Here [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328090.aspx) is nice info about composing a POST http request, but I am missing the Authorization part... Any idea guys?

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595798.aspx

Comment: Can you please help me on how to get access token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a valid `GET` request to pull back accounts.

```
GET https://<CRM DOMAIN>.com/api/data/v8.1/accounts HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer:<TOKEN GOES HERE>
Host: <CRM DOMAIN>.com
```

And here is a valid `POST`

```
POST https://<CRM DOMAIN>.com/api/data/v8.1/accounts HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer:<TOKEN GOES HERE>
Host: <CRM DOMAIN>.com
Content-Length: 224

{
    "name": "Sample Account",
    "creditonhold": false,
    "address1_latitude": 47.639583,
    "description": "This is the description of the sample account",
    "revenue": 5000000,
    "accountcategorycode": 1
}
```